# Disable route prefix for only one route

Tags: symfony

With Symfony 5, I use prefix (`fr`, `en`, `es`) for my routes :

`/routes/annotations.yaml` :

```
controllers:
    resource: ../../src/Controller/
    type: annotation
    prefix: /{_locale}
    requirements:
        _locale: '%app_locales%'
    defaults:
        _locale: '%locale%'
```

But I want to disable the prefix **for only one route**.

In `/routes/annotations.yaml` **before the previous code**, I put this without prefix key :

```
video_play:
    resource: ../../src/Controller/VideoPlayController.php
    type: annotation
```

But my route is still not accessible without the prefix (`404`), I have to put (`fr`, `en`, `es`) in my browser.

This in my controller :

```
class VideoPlayController extends BaseController
{
    /**
     * @Route(
     *     "/video-play/{_token}",
     *     name="video_play",
     *     methods="GET"
     * )
     * @Entity("userMedia", expr="repository.findOneByToken(_token)")
     */
    public function videoPlay(
        UserMedia $userMedia
    ): Response {
        ...
```

Comment: The routes are compiled and overriden in the order that they are defined, move your `video_play` after the "main" definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @msg said, routes are overridden based on their order.

Try to move your `video_play` configuration after

```
controllers:
    resource: ../../src/Controller/
    type: annotation
    prefix: /{_locale}
    requirements:
        _locale: '%app_locales%'
    defaults:
        _locale: '%locale%'

video_play:
    resource: ../../src/Controller/VideoPlayController.php
    type: annotation
```